# Find MongoDB documents where value from one field is not null and not present in a different field

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo

I'm attempting to select a single document which has a field value that is not present and not null for a different field in the same collection.  Here's a simplified representation of the documents in my collection.

```py
"item" : {
    id: "abc",
    previousid: null
},
"item" : {
    id: "def",
    previousid: "abc"
},
"item" : {
    id: "pqr",
    previousid: "def"
},
"item" : {
    id: "xyz",
    previousid: "pqr"
}
```

I need to find the record with an id that has **not** been used as a previousid **and** who's previousid is **not** null.  In the above case, I would expect the last record (version "xyz") to be returned as "xyz" has not been used as a previousid. It's the self-referential stuff that's giving me trouble.

In pseudo code, it would be:

```
select item where id does not exist as previousid and previousid is not null
```

I'm relatively new to MongoDB (but not to databases).  I've pored over the docs for hours and tried numerous methods such as `$ne`, `$nin`, `$and` and `$expr`, but I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$graphLookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) to check the existence of the field in the specified collection and filter the documents where the document doesn't exist for the `priviousId`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "collection",
    "startWith": "$id",
    "connectFromField": "id",
    "connectToField": "previousid",
    "as": "data"
  }},
  { "$match": { "data": [] }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jMfbqP36t7E)

Comment: Thanks.  This appears to do what I need in principle. Would it be possible to add another field to the search, e.g. a string match against an arbitrary value?

Answer (score 0):

Considering below is your collection data

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      id: "abc",
      previousid: null
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      id: "def",
      previousid: "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      id: "pqr",
      previousid: "pqr"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      id: "xyz",
      previousid: "pqr"
    }
  }
]
```

You can get your result in one query as :

```
collectionName.find({
  "item.previousid": {
    $ne: null
  },
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      "$item.id",
      "$item.previousid"
    ]
  }
})
```

giving you the result:

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "def",
      "previousid": "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "xyz",
      "previousid": "pqr"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm afraid this still provides two items.  I need to return the single record with 'xyz' as it's the only item with an id that has not been used as a previousid.